# method.invoke - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, reflection

Any idea?

I got an error, when trying to invoke an object.

```
R java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java(Compiled Code))
at com.test.corp.name.workflow.changetracking.changeimpl.FieldValueChange.apply(FieldValueChange.java:171)
```

```
 public void apply(DomainContext context) {
    try {
        final Class entityClazz = Class.forName(entityClass);
        Object entity = context.getEntity( entityClazz, primaryKey);
        Object entityChange = context.getChangeEntity(entityClazz, primaryKey);
        Method setter = getSetterMethod(entityClazz,fieldName);

        if(entity!=null)
            setter.invoke(entity, new Object[]{getValue()}); //this line 171
        if(entityChange!=null)
            setter.invoke(entityChange, new Object[]{getValue()});

    }catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I think this is enough, but still errors, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

What it says is that `entity` is not of the class `entityClazz`. When you call via reflection `setter.invoke` it expect an object of that class, of course.

Try to output `entity.getClass()` and `entityClazz` and see if they are the same or at least `entityClazz` is parent of `entity.getClass()`.